# Help with recreating Wordpress image upload with ASP MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm trying to recreate the Wordpress image upload feature in MVC3 where a pop-up allows you to insert the image url and edit the image properties like the alt tag, size and position after it has been uploaded to the server. I tried playing around with jqueryUi and an uploading ActionResult and was able to upload the file, but I'm now stumped trying to return the uploaded URL back to the pop-up.

Anyone tried and succeeded with this?

**EDIT:**

Here is my ActionResult that uploads and preps the uploaded image url.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    //Below is the path I want returned to mypop-up
    ViewBag.WebPath = "/Content/Uploads/" + fileName;
    }
    //no idea which Return string to use...
}
```

My jqueryui dialog:

```
$('#upload-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Upload Image',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("UploadImagePartial")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Anyone have ideas using json or ajax?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use Ajax to post to a JsonResult action which responds with an object containing the uploaded URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: { imgData: imgData },
    success: function(receive) {
        // Do whatever
    }
})
```

Where your action would look something like

```
public JsonResult Action(string imgData)
{
    // Do whatever upload logic you have
    var imagePath = /* your path */

    return Json(new { path = imagePath });
}
```

Then in your ajax success function you will be able to access the path as such:

`var jsPath = receive.path`

Comment: Where do I put the first code block? Sorry, no exp. with json yet. What I want to do is after I upload the file, I want the url to be brought back to the modal pop-up for verification. But I have no idea what return value to put into my ActionResult to bring me back to the modal popup. Will post my Actionresult above.

Comment: How do I link this with my jqeryui dialog above?

Comment: Sorry mate, never used modal popups, can't help you here